# Signed URLs with App Engine and Google Cloud CDN

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-cdn

We want to used signed URLs to display reports with sensitive data. Why use signed URLs?  We don't want a user to copy the URL and send it to someone.  We don't want the URL visible, such that the URL can manually be manipulated to potentially try to access other sensitive data.

The reports are not media. They don't reside in GCS. Reports are dynamically generated in GAE.

Google Cloud CDN claims it can generate signed URLs and it works with GAE as explained here:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts

However, it looks complicated.  We don't want to set up a separate load balancer.  That's a reason we use GAE.

This documentation says CDN must be "enabled" on the backend.  How?

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls

> Ensure that Cloud CDN is enabled; for instructions, see Using Cloud
> CDN. You can configure signed URLs on a backend before enabling Cloud
> CDN

Following the instructions leads back to the same web page!?!?

If I try to enable CDN it asks for an "origin" and there are none in the drop down it provides.  Perhaps Cloud CDN needs to be enabled for the project or GAE, but how?

Can CDN be used in a simple fashion with GAE? If so, how?

Comment: Use of Cloud CDN requires to configure a Loadbalancer. A serverless NEG is a backend that points to a App Engine and a Cloud CDN needs to be enabled for the Load Balancer created which in turn has a connection to backend service (App engine).

Comment: Thank you for that info.  Too much work to use Cloud CDN simply for signed URLs.

Does anyone know of another method on GCP for generating signed URLs.